# should I use "I've seen", "I saw" or "I see"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

On my another post (["be of something unpleasant" vs. "be unpleasant"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239528/109190)) I said

> I've seen lots of guys using the expression of something (7 hits). I am trying to understand what does that mean.

where I am trying to survey that that kind of expression is not seldom so that my question would be valuable in general.

In this context, should I use "I've seen", "I saw" or "I see"?

Comment: Since you actively searched for examples, rather than passively observing them, "found" might be better than "saw," and you'd want to use the simple past tense with that.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.